# CSS selectors to query by attribute alone, with LXML

Tags: python, css, lxml

I want to get tags where the attribute contains a `{%` like these examples:

```
<a href="{% route xy %}></a>
<img src="{% static xy %}/>
```

The attribute key does not matter.

The best I can come up with is `tag.cssselect[href*={%]` but it matches only `href`s when I want to match all attributes irrespective of the key.

Comment: You have to define for each of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve that using XPath selector -if acceptable. [css selector is translated to XPath anyway](http://lxml.de/cssselect.html)-, like so  :

```
//*[@*[contains(.,'{%')]]
```

The above XPath selects all elements having any attribute containing `"{%"`. The following is a working example for demo :

```
from lxml.html import etree

html = """<div>
<a href="{% route xy %}"></a>
<img src="{% static xy %}"/>
</div>"""
root = etree.fromstring(html)
result = root.xpath("//*[@*[contains(.,'{%')]]")
for r in result:
    print etree.tostring(r)
```

**output :**

```
<a href="{% route xy %}"/>

<img src="{% static xy %}"/>
```